# In JSON what is best way to send or receive color

Tags: json, colors

What is the preferred or recommended way to send or receive color codes via JSON.
is Hex code or RGB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RGB is better.[Hope this link will help you](http://rgb.to/about-help)